# Determining whether a Pandas df column is an array

Tags: python, pandas

I want to see if a column in my dataframe is an actual `list` type in python. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
is_list_field = all([isinstance(_val, list) for _val in df.iloc[:,1] if _val])
```

Does the above seem like it covers all scenarios (nan? empty string, null, etc.), or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is the output of `df.iloc[:,1].dtypes`

Comment: Array or list? Or both?

Comment: @YOLO -- object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fast but at least work

```
df.applymap(lambda x : type(x)==list).all()
A    False
B     True
dtype: bool
```

Data Input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[1,2]]})
```